# How to switch emoji panel and on-screen keyboard smoothly？

Tags: flutter, dart

As Tiktok does, the emoji panel will keep ,or adjust, its height to match on-screen keyboard when it pops up.

But the interesting part is, the panel does NOT raise along with the keyboard, but directly adjust to the target height which is variable （according to keyboard type and language and other aspects）.

How can I achieve a keyboard-responsive behavior like this in Flutter？

[image]

It behaves the same even the keyboard setting is changed before the APP is launched. So it's impossible that the APP knows the keyboard final size before the keyboard is fully popped.